# Delphi FormatFloat

Tags: delphi, format, floating-point-conversion

I have an output txtfile with some float numbers and I like to print in different formats, y try with:

```
FormatFloat('00000;000.0;00.00', val)  
FormatFloat('00.00;000.0;00000', val)
```

But I take wrong outputs. What I need is:

- If val < 10 then output like '00.00'
- If 10 < val < 100 then output like '000.0'
- If val > 100 then output like '00000'

It's a huge amount of float values, so, I need a low processing solution and I think more conditionals will slow down the application. ¿Any advice?

Thank you

Comment: Step 1 is to decide a complete specification. At the moment it is imprecise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using conditional tests to sort the values into separate outputs is not going to affect performance in a significant way. The format process is far more elaborate. One important thing about optimization is to only walk that path if you can measure a performance hit in the actual code.

```
if (val < 10) then
  s := FormatFloat('00.00',val)
else
if (val < 100) then
  s := FormatFloat('000.0',val)
else
  s := FormatFloat('00000',val);
```

Also consider using the thread-safe [FormatFloat](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FormatFloat) with a  supplied `FormatSettings` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that conditionals would work faster, but consider this sketch (care about out-of-range values):

```
const
  FormatString: array[-1..2] of string = ('0.000', '0.00', '0.0', '0');
var
  x: Double;
  i: integer;
begin
  x := 0.314;
  for i := 1 to 4 do begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(FormatFloat(FormatString[Floor(Log10(x))], x));
    x := x * 10;
  end;

0.314
3.14
31.4
314
```

Comment: Don't you think `Floor(Log10(x))` would work faster than `if (val < 10) then ...`?

Comment: `Log10` is ridiculously expensive. I can't imagine it being even remotely faster than evaluating a conditional.  It's also much less readable and intuitive - a conditional clearly spells out the logic in code.  This does not.